# using ||CHR(39)||

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, concatenation, chr

I have this query:

```
select regexp_replace(regexp_substr('a_bcd_efg_hij','[^_]_[^_]+_[^_]+'),regexp_substr('a_bcd_efg_hij','[^_]',2,1),'W')
from dual;


a_Wcd_efg
```

But when I try to rewrite it using `'||chr(39)||'` I receive the error that some parenthesis are missing.

```
select regexp_replace(regexp_substr('||chr(39)||'a_bcd_efg_hij'||chr(39)||','||chr(39)||'[^_]_[^_]+_[^_]+'||chr(39)||'),regexp_substr('||chr(39)||'a_bcd_efg_hij'||chr(39)||','||chr(39)||'[^_]'||chr(39)||',2,1),'||chr(39)||'W'||chr(39)||')
from dual;
```

The output for this query should be: `a_Wcd_efg`
Can you indicate what is wrong?

Comment: **Please** see [Markdown Editing Help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Comment: Although I can't even run your initial working query, I think your main problem is that `'||chr(39)||'middle part'||chr(39)||'` isn't a string. To make a string starting and ending with chr(39), it should be `chr(39)||'middle part'||chr(39)`. chr(39) is a string, so you don't need to add quotations to it and you concatenate it to other strings with || like `'string1'||'string2'` or `chr(39)||'string2'`

Comment: Why do you need to replace single quotes with the `chr()` equivalent?